# Can we build a Finite Determinist Automaton from any Nondeterminist Finite Automaton?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is it possible to create a Determinist Finite Automaton that is equivalent to a Nondeterminist Finite Automaton, whatever that NFA is ?

Is there an algorithm to create such a DFA if we have a NFA ?

Comment: We expect you to do a significant amount of research to try to answer your question on your own, before asking, and show us what you found.  Your question is answered here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Closure_properties.  If your question can be answered by looking in the obvious place on Wikipedia, you probably should do more research before asking. There's little point in us repeating material already documented well in standard resources.

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is called the [subset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have mentioned, yes! NFAs and DFAs are equivalent, and there is a deterministic algorithm to convert any NFA to a DFA. Likewise any DFA is an NFA without any reduction.